# Charge Plugin v2.2.1: Variable subscription amounts

Tags: plugin-charge, stripe

What's the best way to accomplish a variable subscription amount with the Charge plugin? I.e. the Stripe payment amount needs to change from month to month.

As an example, say a subscription is £0.99 each month, and then additional purchases are £0.99 on top of this, can I update the subscription somehow before the charge date with the final amount, or can I put through additional payments each month using the Stripe ID attached to the subscription?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For anyone looking for help with this problem, this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079342/can-i-update-subscription-amount-after-subscribed-in-stripe may be useful. I'm in the process of building a Craft CMS / Charge specific solution using the Stripe invoice.created webhook and create invoice API call. I'll will post the final code / steps here once everything is working.